# How to write a stored procedure to get 3 different types of records using different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a set of records in a table with these columns:

```
Id  aId Sid SerId   St  CreatedTime      DateTime           by
1   2    23  34     2   7/1/2014 13:00   11/12/2014 23:40   A
```

In the above table the values for the column will be 2, 3 or 4. for St it will be again 2, 3 or 4. Now I want to select 3 rows from this table. those 3 rows shoule be having values like this.

1. It should be having the highest date time and its st value should be in (2,3,4) and aId value should be 2
2. It should be having the highest date time and its st value should be in (2,3,4) and aId value should be 3
3. It should be having the highest date time and its st value should be in (2,3,4) and aId value should be 3

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by aid, st order by DateTime desc) rn 
            from tablename
            where (aid = 2 and st = 2) or (aid = 3 and st = 3) or (aid = 4 and st = 4))
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Explanation: First filter for `aid` and `st` pairs with `2, 3, 4` values. Then number rows from 1 ordered by `DateTime` column descending while partitioning on `aid` and `st` value.

It is not clear but you may want this:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by aid order by DateTime desc) rn 
            from tablename
            where aid in(2, 3, 4) and st in(2, 3, 4))
select * from cte where rn = 1
```